# Hide a row in table based on the selected option from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I'm trying to figure out on hiding a row that contains "Grade 6 Class" in one of its `<td>` **IF** I'll choose Grade 1 in Select Grade Level after clicking the btn_search.

[image]

The options are coming from the database. I know there's another way to do it where you simply add an option instead of getting it from the database, but that method seems to work differently and I'm not really into trying it, you know.

[image]

**This is my select element:**

```
<select required onchange="section_add_nd(this);" id="selc_gr_id" data-style="btn-primary" class="form-control input-sm">
<option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Grade Level --</option>
</select>
```

**This is how I retrieve the data from database and propagate it as an options:**

```
function sy_add_nd(e){

    let api_url = "../fetch.php";
    let gr = document.getElementById('selc_gr_id');
    let arr_pos = e.value.split(':')[1];

    fetch(api_url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =(data)=>{
        $gr_level = '<option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Grade Level --</option>';
        data[arr_pos]['gradelvl'].forEach(function(data){
            $gr_level+='<option value="'+data['yid']+':'+arr_pos+'">'+data['level_name']+'</option>';
        });
        gr.innerHTML = $gr_level;
        document.getElementById('sc_add_nd').innerHTML='<option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Section --</option>';
    });
}
```

I tried to use `if (...==='Grade 1')` with the code below that I found here in stack. By calling a function from outside or by executing it inside :

```
document.getElementById('btn_search').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var selectedGrade = document.getElementById('selc_gr_id').value;
  var selectedSection = document.getElementById('sc_add_nd').value;

  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var gradeCell = rows[i].getAttribute('data-grade');
    var sectionCell = rows[i].getAttribute('data-section');

    if (gradeCell === selectedGrade && sectionCell === selectedSection) {
      rows[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  if (selectedGrade === 'Grade 1') {
    var tdcollection = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < tdcollection.length; i++) {
      if (tdcollection[i].innerText.indexOf("Grade 6 Class") >= 0) {
        tdcollection[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Although, that code above that would hide the row works **ONLY** if I didn't put it inside the if else.
The reason why I am using it because I cannot filter the table that will only show a data like 'Grade 1 Class' if I choose Grade 1 class. It will show other data like 'Grade 6 Class'

I really appreciate your kindness, really do. Thank you so much and for taking a look at this problem!

**UPDATE:**

This is what the option value looks like after retrieving the data from database:
[image]

Comment: This is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks for informing! It's just some code contains php and it's because I'm using it inside .php file.

Comment: _"It's just some code contains php and it's because I'm using it inside .php file."_ - What does that mean? What is the question about? JS? PHP? SQL? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The Section dropdown doesn't have anything in it. So `sectionCell === selectedSection` will never be true.